# what is the best way to create database using titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-modules

I have below 2 approach to create Db in titanium. Need to know which is the best approach out of these 2.

**Approach 1** -- Create a sqlite database using a tool like 'SQLite Manager' and copying that database to app and using it.

**Approach 2** -- Create a sqlite database, using queries in the titanium code. like Ti.Database.open("DBName"); and then create tables using sqlite queries

thanks
amit

Comment: You can sort out all the requirements before going into it. In my opinion, u should go with approach 1. With 2nd approach, should be use  to query db not for creation of db.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the database is always going to be read-only, I'd go with #1.  But if it will contain user entered data, you will eventually need to do #2 if you ever need to update the design of the database.

I've had apps that I needed to add features - that required new tables / indexes.  You can't use approach #1 to modify a 'Version 1' database to your new design.

Comment: yes but even if you put creation of tables in queries, you would still need to re-install the app for the changes to take effect, and i guess that will flush out the database with data. Still a lil confused here....

Comment: No...upgrading the app will not flush the database. When you call Ti.Database.open it copies or creates a database in the users' Documents directory. If you upgrade the design of your 'template' database in approach #1 (which is in the Resources directory) those design changes will not be pushed to the users' copy of the database if it has already be copied.